# How can I set frame border shape of the widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I set frame border shape of the widgets in Flutter like this ?

[image]

*The stars⭐ are image file (.PNG)*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You ca easily implement this with `Stack` widget. Just take a quick look at this link: [Flutter Stack Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)